# Searching for the nearest file name in many folders

Tags: c#, linq, io

I have 1 directory.

Inside that 1 directory I have, on this occasion 10 sub folders.

In each of these sub folders there are 'n' number of files.

The filename of each file follows this format:

yyyymmddhhmissfff.jpg

Where:

yyyy = year value
mm   = month value
dd   = day value
hh   = hour value
mi   = minute value
ss   = second value
fff  = milisecond value.

So what I am trying to do, for instance I am searching for the closest file name to 20140316182212*.jpg.  I know I can do this:

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And then I enumerate through the results to get the closest filename.

But is there a linq way of doing this more efficiently? Incidentally. I cannot rely on the creation timestamp of the file because there is no guarantee the filename will match the creation date.

Comment: There is no other way to find a file by some random criteria than iterating over all files and checking criteria. You can indeed write some LINQ query to do the search, but it will not be any more efficient (likely you'll be able to get it correct sooner than hand-written iteration). I.e. some sort of `OrderBy (name=> DateTime.ParseExact(name, "yyyyMMddHHmmssf", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)-timeOfMyFile)` can be starting point of finding the one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the confirmation. I thought as much but I wanted to open the question out.  Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var file = "20140316182212.jpg";    
var fileNum = Convert.ToInt64(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));

var minDiff = Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Select(path => Convert.ToInt64(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)))
             .Min(num => Math.Abs(fileNum - num));

var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .First(path => Math.Abs(fileNum - Convert.ToInt64(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path))) == minDiff);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
string path = "C:\\YourFolderName\\";
string filePath = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.JPG", SearchOption.AllDirectories).First(f => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f).Contains("20140316182212"));
```

Comment: Hi, It was kind of you to reply but that is less efficient than what I have already. Also, I was asking a question about linq - but thanks for your time :)

Comment: it is lambda expression with extension method . it is like linq. it is linq equivalent `var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories) where file.Contains("20140316182212") select file;`

Comment: hi, sorry I did not scroll to the end. I will look at this now. Thanks

Comment: That code won't work though from what I can tell. It has a `.Contains()` statement on the end, which is not what the original post is asking for. The original post is asking to find the _nearest_ filename to the timestamp, not an exact match.